# exit pointerlockcontrols three.js not working

Tags: javascript, function, three.js, pointerlock

I have the following code to lock the cursor (this works fine):

```
var element = document.body;

var controls;
var instructions = document.getElementById( 'start' );
var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document || 'mozPointerLockElement' in document || 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;

if ( havePointerLock ) {


    var pointerlockchange = function ( event ) {

        if ( document.pointerLockElement === element || document.mozPointerLockElement === element || document.webkitPointerLockElement === element ) {

            controlsEnabled = true;
            controls.enabled = true;

        } else {

            controlsEnabled = false;
            controls.enabled = false;

            instructions.style.display = '';

        }

    };

    var pointerlockerror = function ( event ) {

        instructions.style.display = '';

    };

    // Hook pointer lock state change events
    document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );

    instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        instructions.style.display = 'none';

        // Ask the browser to lock the pointer
        element.requestPointerLock = element.requestPointerLock || element.mozRequestPointerLock || element.webkitRequestPointerLock;

        if ( /Firefox/i.test( navigator.userAgent ) ) {

            document.addEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );

            element.requestFullscreen = element.requestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullscreen;

            element.requestFullscreen();

        } else {

            element.requestPointerLock();

        }

    }, false );

} else {

    instructions.innerHTML = 'Your browser doesn\'t seem to support my epic Portfolio';

}
```

when i run a function i want the pointerlockcontrols to be disabled so i can use my mouse again. so i tried the following:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    element.exitPointerLock;

}
```

this doesnt give me any errors but i also dont get my mouse back why is this?

when i try:

```
element.exitPointerLock();
```

i get element.exitPointerLock is not a function

so i dont know how to fix this :( any suggestions would be great if you need more code or a jsfiddle just ask me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so i figured it out :D i had to change:

```
element.exitPointerLock();
```

to:

```
document.exitPointerLock();
```

then it all works fine! hope this helps someone :)